# How to migrate data from a table in one database to another successfully in mssql

Tags: sql-server, database

I have 2 major problems while Migrating my data from a database to another.

1. Sql query `insert into FlexSchoolDemo.dbo.BursaryFeeMaster([FeeName]) select  [FeeType] from FlexUni.dbo.Bursary_FeeMaster`

Error `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IsSchoolFee', table 'FlexSchoolDemo.dbo.BursaryFeeMaster'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.`

While Migrating this data, the destination table contains some columns with `bool` attribute one of which is `IsSchoolFee` and now the error says `cannot insert the Value NULL into the column IsSchoolFee`. How do i migrate this successfully without having to change the bool parameters?

2. Sql Query `insert into FlexSchoolDemo.dbo.StApplicationsOlevel([ApplicationNo],[JambregNo],[SubjectId],[GradeId]) select  [JambregNo],[JambregNo],[SubjectID],[GradeID] from FlexUni.dbo.Student_Applications_Olevel`

Error `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_StApplicationsOlevel_AdmSubjectGrades_GradeId". The conflict occurred in database "FlexSchoolDemo", table "dbo.AdmSubjectGrades", column 'GradeId'.`

While Migrating this data, `SubjectId` and `GradeId` are both foreign keys in their different tables but throws error. How can i also achieve a successful migration too?

Comment: There is no `BOOL` datatype in MS SQL Server.

Comment: First issue. Replace this `insert into FlexSchoolDemo.dbo.BursaryFeeMaster([FeeName]) select  [FeeType] from FlexUni.dbo.Bursary_FeeMaster` on this: `insert into FlexSchoolDemo.dbo.BursaryFeeMaster([FeeName],[IsSchoolFee]) select  [FeeType],[IsSchoolFee] from FlexUni.dbo.Bursary_FeeMaster`

Comment: @МаксимЗолотенко The table `Bursary_FeeMaster ` in `FlexUni` doesn't have the column `[IsSchoolFee]`

Comment: You can use this: `insert into FlexSchoolDemo.dbo.BursaryFeeMaster([FeeName],[IsSchoolFee]) select [FeeType],0 as IsSchoolFee from FlexUni.dbo.Bursary_FeeMaster`